# Stylecop for InstallShield project

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, installshield, code-inspection

I need to make sure that InstallShield has only allowed settings. I would like to run this check on CI server.

In other words in `Component` table I would like to check `Attributes` fields has only allowed values(`<td>8</td>`, `<td>1</td>`)

```
<table name="Component">
    <col key="yes" def="s72">Component</col>
    <col def="S38">ComponentId</col>
    <col def="s72">Directory_</col>
    <col def="i2">Attributes</col>
    <col def="S255">Condition</col>
    <col def="S72">KeyPath</col>
    <col def="I4">ISAttributes</col>
    <col def="S255">ISComments</col>
    <col def="S255">ISScanAtBuildFile</col>
    <col def="S255">ISRegFileToMergeAtBuild</col>
    <col def="S0">ISDotNetInstallerArgsInstall</col>
    <col def="S0">ISDotNetInstallerArgsCommit</col>
    <col def="S0">ISDotNetInstallerArgsUninstall</col>
    <col def="S0">ISDotNetInstallerArgsRollback</col>
        <row>
            <td>Adapter</td>
            <td>{05A86BD3-38F8-40CC-8A16-AB643A555787}</td>
            <td>ADAPTER</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td/>
            <td>adapter.dll</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>/LogFile=</td>
            <td>/LogFile=</td>
            <td>/LogFile=</td>
            <td>/LogFile=</td>
        </row>
```

The straightforward approach would be create PowerShell script to parse the project file as XML, find corresponding values, and make sure they are in allowed range.

Is there more *elegant* way to do so like tool similar to StyleCop? As custom PowerShell script would be expensive to support by its own.

Comment: If you're able, you can use the InstallShield automation interface. See my answer to a different post on an example of using the automation in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42677391/925800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comment from Steve I got working `PowerShell` version without need to manually parse `InstallShield` project file.

Using [Automation Interface](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutomation.htm) It is quite easy to check a component for errorneous configuration.

```
$projectFile = "project.ism"

$project = new-object -comobject IswiAuto16.ISWiProject

$project.OpenProject($projectFile)

Foreach ($feature in $project.ISWiFeatures)
{
    Foreach ($component in $feature.ISWiComponents)
    {
        if(<check $component  for an errorneous config>)
        {
            <report an issue here>
        }
    }
}

$project.CloseProject()
```